# Conditional summation in PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have a `transactions` table which contains a category (`category_id`), an amount (`amount`) and a flag (`managed`) which can be true or false.

I would like to display a list of all categories with the total amounts of managed and not managed transactions, e.g.

```
Category | managed_transactions | unmanaged_transactions
Cat 1    |     124000           |     54000
Cat 2    |     4000             |     0
Cat 3    |     854000           |     1000000
```

Is there a way to do something like

```
Select category_id,
       sum(amount) if (managed is true) as managed_transactions,
       sum(amount) if (managed is false) as unmanaged_transactions
from transactions
```

I'm obviously stuck on the `if managed is true` part...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Enjoy!

```sql
SELECT
  category_id,
  SUM( CASE WHEN managed THEN amount ELSE      0 END ) AS managed_transactions,
  SUM( CASE WHEN managed THEN      0 ELSE amount END ) AS unmanaged_transactions
FROM
  transactions
GROUP BY
  category_id
ORDER BY
  category_id
```

Comment: ah! thanks, I had tried `case when managed sum(amount) end` but it was the other way round :o)